# how to get an image in drawable when button is clicked in android studio?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to know how to get an image in `drawable` and put it in an `imageview` when button is clicked.

```
public void Btna(){
    btna = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btna);
    btna.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
                    img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boron);



                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a field in your `activity` for `ImageView` & in `onCreate()` of `activity` to initialize that image like...

```
img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
```

Then change image in `onClickListener()` for that button.

```
 img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.monkey);
```

Answer (score 0):

**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView Image;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;

        Image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
        Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```